# $\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(c*x)} < \frac{g(x)}{g(x)-g(c*x)}$ for $f$, linear, $g$ concave and $c\in (0,1)$?

Tags: functions, inequality

where $f$ is linear **through the origin**, and $g$ is concave, and  we are only considering the positive real numbers. (and $f,g$ are both strictly increasing)

Is the statement in the title true? I can't seem to find a counterexample.

If it is true, could someone help with a proof? I have been trying to prove using a Taylor expansion and the definition of convexity, but I'm not able to yet.

I feel like if it is true, it somehow follows from the definition of concavity?

(if $f$ is not linear through the origin I believe I am able to find counterxamples (just add a huge constant to make the numerator much larger than the denominator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the definition of concavity and linearity. 
$$\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(cx)}<\dfrac{g(x)}{g(x)-g(cx)}$$
$$\iff \dfrac{1}{1-c}<\dfrac{g(x)}{g(x)-g(cx)}$$
$$\iff g(x)-g(cx)<g(x)-cg(x)$$
$$\iff g(cx)>cg(x)$$
By definition of concavity we have
$$g(cx)=g(cx+(1-c)0)$$
$$>cg(x)+(1-c)g(0)$$
So we are done if $g(0)\ge 0$. Otherwise, this proposition may not hold. For example, take $g(x)=-5-(x-3)^2, c=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $x=2$. Then $$g(cx)=g(1)=-9$$
$$cg(x)=-3$$

Comment: Thank you for the help and the answer

Comment: You're welcome, @user106860.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is perhaps easy to see as follows:

First note that, for any line through the origin, $\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(y)}$ is the same, regardless of slope.

Now consider a concave function $G$, and two points $x,y$, with $x>y$.

We can construct a line through the origin going to $f(x)$. But from the first note we know what $\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(y)}$ is, but for this concave function the denominator must be smaller (by definition of concavity?)

> If someone could provide intuition though, it would be much appreciated.